# Ill-posedness of a Cauchy Problem for the Heat Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, stability-theory

We consider the annulus
\begin{align*}
A = B_4(0,0)\setminus B_1(0,0)
\end{align*}
in $\mathbb{R}^2$. And let $J$ be the segment in $A$
\begin{align*}
J = \{(x,y) \in A : 2<x<3, y=0 \}.
\end{align*}

Can someone help me figure out whether the following Cauchy problem is ill-posed? And if so, why?

\begin{align}\label{cauchy prob}
\begin{cases}
z_t-\Delta z = 0& \qquad \text{on $A \times (0,T)$;} \\
z(x,0,t) = 0& \qquad \text{on $J\times (0,T)$;}\\
z_y(x,0,t) = 0& \qquad \text{on $J\times (0,T)$.}\\
\end{cases}
\end{align}

Thank you in advance

Comment: Seems this reduces to showing the trivial solution, $z = 0$, is unique.

Comment: This amounts to proving uniqueness of solutions for the heat equation, which is a well known problem.

Comment: Thank you. I think that can be shown by showing that all partial derivatives w.r.t. $x$ and $y$  of $z(x,0,t)$ are $0$ and the fact that $(x,y) \rightarrow z(x,y,t)$ is analytic in $A \times (0,T)$, fixing $ t_0 \in (0,T)$. Since $t_0$ was fixed arbitrarily in $(0,T)$, it follows that $z(x,y,t) \equiv 0$. Maybe i'm too easy about that last step though. Mostly, I don't see how it follows that small errors in the initial data lead to uncontrollable errors in the solution?